# Starting activity from a non-Activity class with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

Is it possible to start an activity from a non-Activity class with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

I have a non-Activity class that, upon certain conditions, needs to launch an intent to an activity. I'm currently doing it as such:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, myActivity.class);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

This works, but I do not wish to start the activity as a new task. Instead, I'd like to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but this gives me the following runtime System.err:

Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: If you start any activity without activity context, then you have to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, because you are deviating from the activity continuity. Hope you are trying to start activity with service or broadcast receiver context.

Comment: Thanks. It's a class that's being called by a receiver to handle events. I'm trying to bring the app back to a login activity in the event the app is detected to have been logged out for some reason, and I don't want to create a new task else logging out later manually will not work, but rather bring the user to the earlier instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the flags (ie: use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`).

However, if the existing task does NOT have an active (non-finished) instance of `myActivity` in it, it will not clear anything and it will just create a new instance of `myActivity` on the top of the stack.